# Two-way relationships in Laravel Factories with Faker

Tags: php, laravel, faker, factories

I have two Modals that I'm trying to write factories for. LineItems and Invoices. The problem is that they are dynamic based on each other.

```
Table: line_items
id | amount | invoice
1  | 15     | 1 
2  | 10     | 1 
3  | 15     | 2
4  | 5      | null

Table: invoices
id | total
1  | 25   
2  | 15
```

LineItems know which Invoice they are assigned to, and Invoices save the total value of the LineItems assigned to them.

LineItems would look like this:

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\LineItems::class, function (Faker $faker) {
  return [
    'amount' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 15),
    'invoice' => null
  ];
});
```

And then to build a factory for the Invoices, I need to sum the amounts from LineItems, no big deal, I can create LineItems inside the factory and total:

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\Invoice::class, function (Faker $faker) {
  $total = 0;

  $line_items = $factory(\App\Models\LineItems::class, 3);

  foreach($line_items as $l) {
    $total += $l->amount;
  }

  return [
    'total' => $total
  ];
});
```

But now the problem is, **how do I save the Invoice `id` number back to the LineItems I just created?** Obviously, I don't have the `id` until the factory is saved, which is after the Closure callback is finished. I can't return the LineItems out of the Closure because the factory needs to use the return so it can actually save the Invoice.

I know this seems like an X/Y problem. But I've looked through some of the similar questions here on SO, and I'm not a fan of the workarounds because they are super fragile, relying on non-obvious orders of operation or for certain data to already exist before you can run a factory. I'd rather find a solution using factories and just keep all the concerns local if possible.

Plus, if there is a solution, it means the factories are self-sustaining, which is better for all concerned. But if this is not possible, that would be an acceptable answer since it allows me to pursue other (albeit more fragile) means of saving test data.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson Laravel 5.5

Comment: I was going to say that if you're using >= 5.6.12 that you could have used the `afterCreating()` method.

Comment: Ah damn, that would be useful.

Comment: I wonder why is the `total` is not computed but stored as integer... prone to errors. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 - With Seed**

First, the LineItems factory set some random invoice

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\LineItems::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'amount' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 15),
        'invoice' => function () {
             return factory(\App\Models\Invoice::class)->create()->id;
        },
    ];
});
```

Then create a Invoice without the dependency

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\Invoice::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'total' => 0
    ];
});
```

Then you create a seed to populate the way you want

```
class InvoiceSeederClass extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $invoice = factory(App\Models\Invoice::class)->create();

        $lineItems = factory(App\Models\LineItems::class, 3)->create([
            'invoice' => $invoice->id,
        ]);

        $total = 0;
        foreach($lineItems as $item) {
            $total += $item->amount;
        }

        $invoice->amount = $total;
        $invoice->save();
    }
}

$seeder = new InvoiceSeederClass();
$seeder->run();
```

Now the factories have the logic are isolated, and you can create with your own business logic.

---

**Method 2 - With Dummy Factory**

Create LineItems factory

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\LineItems::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'amount' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 15),
        'invoice' => function () {
             return factory(\App\Models\Invoice::class)->create()->id;
        },
    ];
});
```

Create Invoice factory

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\Invoice::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'total' => 0
    ];
});
```

Create Dummy factory

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\DummyFactory::class, function () use($faker) {
    $invoice = factory(App\Models\Invoice::class)->create();

    $lineItems = factory(App\Models\LineItems::class, 3)->create([
        'invoice' => $invoice->id,
    ]);

    $total = 0;
    foreach($lineItems as $item) {
        $total += $item->amount;
    }

    $invoice->amount = $total;
    $invoice->save();

    return []; // you can return any array you want, ex. $invoice
});
```

Usage. Important: use MAKE instead of CREATE:

```
$invoiceWithItems = factory(App\Models\DummyFactory::class)->make();
```

Now your logic is inside a factory

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this presents the same problem, but in reverse. How would I get the total amount saved back to the Invoice? Are you suggesting just querying it with eloquent and updating it normally in the seeder?

Comment: I forgot that. But all you need is to add your own logic.

Comment: Edited. You can use a "dummyfactory" to generate your data inside a factory instead of a seeder